# REGEXP_EXTRACT in hive or Impala to extract a Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hql, impala

Hi i am new to hive i am using regexp_extract for getting substring from a string

my fixmessagestr is `10123=TICKET~}|167=CS~}|1=XTL9911~}|336=REG~}|10120= ~}|111=909~}|`

how will I get `XTL9911` using regexp_extract function. Need to get value for 1 Tag

I am using below and

select `regexp_extract(fixmessagestr, '}1=(.*?)', 1)` and it's giving `null`

Comment: please remove all tags which are not applicable. Read what hql is.

Answer (score 0):

In your string there is pipe `|` before tag- `1`, not curly brace. Anyway both pipe and curly brace are special characters in regexp and should be shielded by double backslash (in Hive/Impala, in other databases it can be single backslash), also add end character, it is `~`:

```
select regexp_extract('10123=TICKET~}|167=CS~}|1=XTL9911~}|336=REG~}|10120= ~}|111=909~}|', \
                     '\\|1=(.*?)~', 1)
```

Result:

```
XTL9911
```